# div area expanded unintentionally when using column-count

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make masonry-like layout by using column-count property.

Here is my CSS code.

```
.masonry {
    column-count: 2;
      column-gap: 1em;
}
  
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

and HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="content">
            <div class="masonry">
                <div class="item"><img src="img/horizon1.png" /></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/horizon2.png" /></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/horizon3.png" /></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works well when all images are horizontal.

[It works well when all images are horizontal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5bwB.png)

But when I use vertical image file, suddenly .masonry expands below unintentionally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="content">
            <div class="masonry">
                <div class="item"><img src="img/horizon1.png" /></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/horizon2.png" /></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/vertical.png" /></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

[.masonry expands below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lE1h.png)

(I use big images, for responsive.)

When I use very small vertical image, then there is no unnecessary space.

[then there is no unnecessary space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4nZ7.png)

It seems to be happened due to image size, but I don't know why.
How can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your overall desired layout is ? It's very likely the "problem" is related to `display: inline-block;` but without knowing the exact goal there are 100 different possible fixes.

Comment: Most likely you'd be much happier with a `display: grid` based setup; but i dont know if there should always be 2 columns, if there are always 3 cells (2 in col1 and 1 in col2) etc. i dont know if the overall masonry should cover the whole page/parent or take up minimal space; should the columns grow wider if the image is wider, ....

Comment: @Raxi

Thanks for your answer.
I want use this layout in the article of my Wordpress site related to photograph.
Something like this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PocB.png).

Columns are should be two always, but the number of photos and their aspect ratio can be many kinds.
(It depends of which photos I use.)
I tried to use display: grid, but I cannot use it well because for the above reason.